# Communication between Processing and C# app?

Tags: c#, ipc, processing

I would like to pass an object from a C# application to be processed? How may I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a socket and pass the data over TCP using the [Network library](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/net/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to implement a **queue** of some sort.  Reasons:

- This ensures that your objects can queue up while processing occurs.
- If the processor is down, you don't lose any submitted objects as they will wait in the queue.
- Decouples your C# application and your processing service (or whatever it may be)

The type of queue you need depends on your environment.  Here are two good options:

- [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [how to interface with it in C#](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=C%23+MSMQ&rlz=1C1CHMO_enZA522ZA522&aq=f&oq=C%23+MSMQ&aqs=chrome.0.57j58j62l3.3841j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#rlz=1C1CHMO_enZA522ZA522&sclient=psy-ab&q=C%23+MSMQ&oq=C%23+MSMQ&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.148078.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c..14.psy-ab.GQhSYioS5ok&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.ZGU&fp=1183248d3b0335d4&biw=2560&bih=1276) for local or network-based applications
- [Windows Azure Queue or Service Bus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx) if you working in the Azure cloud